# Redirect port 3389 with iptables, to an IP network

Tags: iptables

I have on my network a linux server and it iptables firewall.
On the same network, you have a Windows Server 2008 server.
When I'm out of my network, I access the Server 2008 for RDP and this service applies to port 3389.
When I enter my endereçoexterno: 3389 it will point in my server with iptables.
So iptabes should redirect the request to the ip Windows Server2008.

Comment: question edited...

Answer (score 1):

I resolved my issue.
Iptables script follows:

```
/sbin/iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -j DNAT --to --dport 3389 192.168.100.21:3389
/sbin/iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp --dport 3389 192.168.100.21 d j ACCEPT
```

[image]

```
Eth0 -> Board receiving the internret
192.168.100.21 -> Terminal Server ip in ETH1
3389 -> default port remote access rdp
```